# Build docker image, tag with built image id, push the image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

*Background: Running Kubernetes on Google Cloud.*

Because Kubernetes won't tolerate `:latest` tag for Rolling Updates, I'd find something like this useful.

```
docker build . -t gcr.io/project/nginx:{built_image_id} && docker push gcr.io/project/nginx:{built_image_id}
```

I saw a blog post about using git commit hash as a tag. Any other alternatives to skip the "copy git hash step"?

Thanks

Comment: If this is a counter-practice, let me know.

Comment: Semver - https://semver.org/

Comment: like that: `docker tag myimage:1.2.3 myimage:$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)`

Comment: Date stamps; the build number from your CI server; a sequential commit number from an SCM that supports it (Subversion, Mercurial, Perforce); a more complicated `git describe` invocation that uses the current branch name and a sequential commit number; ...

Answer (score 0):

According to Kubernetes [documentations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/#updating-the-container-image):

“ Doing a rolling update from image:latest to a new image:latest will fail, even if the image at that tag has changed. Moreover, the use of :latest is not recommended,”

They provided some best practices for configuration to help, that you can check in the following [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images) and use as a guide.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Kubernetes docs doesn't explain the image build process. I wanted a single line command that builds, tags and pushes with a label that makes sense. Denis's answer does the job.

Answer (score 0):

From Denis's answer. I got this, which should do the job.

`docker build . -t gcr.io/project/nginx:$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) && docker push gcr.io/project/nginx:$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)`